# Formatar data em javascript

Tags: javascript, data

O código possui um array que recebe as informações do DB. O campo data recebe a data no formato YYYY-MM-DD, mas eu gostaria de exibir ela na seguinte ordem DD-MM-YYYY.

Poderiam me auxiliar com alguma função ou uma dica em como tratar esse problema?

```
for(var i=0;dados.length>i;i++){
    $('#table').append(  
        "<td align = 'left' style='width:40px;max-width:40px;'<b>"+dados[i].Conta+"</b> </td>"+  
        "<td align = 'left' style='width:50px;max-width:50px;'><b>"+dados[i].codigoAcesso+"</b> </td>"+  
        "<td align = 'left' style='width:50px;max-width:50px;'><b>"+dados[i].nome+"</b> </td>"+  
        "<td align = 'left' style='width:50px;max-width:50px;'><b>"+dados[i].data+"</b> </td>"+  
        "</table>"
    ); 
};
```

Comment: Obrigado Caique!
Apesar de tratar do mesmo assunto, a minha maior dificuldade é pegar a data do array e formatá-la. Esse foi o motivo pelo qual eu optei em criar uma nova pergunta.

Comment: Pegar a data do array é fazer `dados[i].data`, interpreta-la e formata-la é exatamente o que aparece na duplicata indicada pelo @CaiqueRomero. Tem N soluções, tanto manuais, como como bibliotecas

Answer (score 1):

Você já tentou obter os dados referente a data em variáveis separadas e depois junta-la em uma nova variável? Ficaria assim:

```
var data=new Date()
var dia=data.getDate();
var mes=data.getMonth();
var ano=data.getFullYear();
data = dia + '/' + (mes++) + '/' + ano;
```

Comment: Certo, vou fazer esse teste e já retorno!

Answer (score 1):

Se for uma string "YYYY-MM-DD" e você quer obter outra string " DD-MM-YYYY" pode fazer assim

```
"YYYY-MM-DD".split("-").reduce(function(p, c){ return c + "-" +p })
```

ou criar uma função para este intuito

```
function f(str){ return str.split("-").reduce(function(p, c){ return c + "-" +p })}
```

e converter em ambos os sentidos [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]